# Is there any way to blacklist a folder from address sanitizer when using GCC?

Tags: gcc, memory-management, compilation, address-sanitizer

So I have enabled `-fsantize=address` to write a good program.

However, quite a bit of issues was being caught by other libraries that are not written by me (for ex, /lib64/...so)

I looked into `-fsantize-blacklist` option but seems like it's only available for clang not for GCC.

I know you can blacklist specific functions in your source code. But to be honest, that is not the ideal way as I wouldn't know which function will cause the issue ahead of time.

Is there any way to prevent GCC from processing address sanitizer for files under a specific folder?

Please help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `fsanitize-blacklist` has been rejected by GCC maintainers several times and there's no equivalent option. You could add Clang support or use `-fsanitize-recover=address` together with `export ASAN_OPTIONS=log_path=path/to/logs` to collect errors from all libraries and then filter the ones that are relevant.

Comment: I'm curious what they think the use for this functionality is if it cannot be used when possibly faulty third-party libraries are involved …